# Jquery selectable: Find selected elements length

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-selectable

```
$( ".mylist" ).selectable({
        cancel: 'a',
        selected:function(event, ui) {
           console.log($(ui));
        }
    })
```

I would like to print the number of selected elements in the selected function. How do i do that?

Comment: Perhaps you should show the html code, it would be easier to find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Selected elements with jQuery UI selectable get the `.ui-selected` class, so you can just use `$(".ui-selected").length`.

If you have multiple selectables on the same page, you will have to narrow it down using the parent.